# How can I do this Query on SQL Server 2008 without TSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to make a query but I don't know how to do it. I'm a newbie in SQL querying, so please be patient.

Here is what I have:

```
select 
    count(*), sum(time), 'peter' 
from 
    (select * 
     from ACTUATION 
     where OPERATOR != 'peter' 
       and team in (select eq1.name 
                        from TEAMWORKS eq1 
                        where operator1 = 'peter' 
                           or operator2 = 'peter' 
                           or operator3 = 'peter' 
                           or operator4 = 'peter' 
                           or operator5 = 'peter' 
                           or operator6 = 'peter' 
                           or operator7 = 'peter' )) as a
```

This works OK, **but I need to do it for every operator in the table `operators` and don't know how to do it.**

I've tried several subqueries and groups by, but I can not make it work properly.

Kind regards

---

EDIT:
Let's say I have this DataBase:

```
create table TEAMWORKS 
(
    operator1 varchar(50),
    operator2 varchar(50),
    operator3 varchar(50),
    operator4 varchar(50),
    operator5 varchar(50),
    operator6 varchar(50),
    operator7 varchar(50),
    name varchar(50)
) 

insert into TEAMWORKS (operator1,operator2,name) values ('Peter', 'Paul', 'Pe-Pa')
insert into TEAMWORKS (operator2,operator3,name) values ('Peter', 'John', 'Pe-Jo')
insert into TEAMWORKS (operator1,operator4,name) values ('John', 'Paul', 'Jo-Pa')
insert into TEAMWORKS (operator5,operator6,name) values ('John', 'Peter', 'Jo-Pe')


create table OPERATORS 
(
    name varchar(50),
    surname varchar(50)
) 

insert into OPERATORS (name,surname) values ('Peter', 'Font')
insert into OPERATORS (name,surname) values ('Paul', 'Bridges')
insert into OPERATORS (name,surname) values ('John', 'Oldfield')


create table ACTUATION  
(
    ID int,
    time int,
    operator varchar(50),
    team varchar(50),
    description varchar(999)
) 

insert into ACTUATION (ID,time,operator,team,description) values (1,30,'Peter', '','Pick flowers')
insert into ACTUATION (ID,time,operator,team,description) values (2,15,'Paul', '','Throw flowers')
insert into ACTUATION (ID,time,operator,team,description) values (3,30,'Peter', 'Jo-Pe','Pick stones')
insert into ACTUATION (ID,time,operator,team,description) values (4,5,'John', 'Jo-Pe','Throw stones')
insert into ACTUATION (ID,time,operator,team,description) values (5,15,'Paul', 'Jo-Pa','Throw tables')
insert into ACTUATION (ID,time,operator,team,description) values (6,30,'Peter', 'Pe-Pa','Pick tables')
```

And I need to get the time used by Every operator in table OPERATORS where he is not the main operator in Table ACTUATIONS, but part of a TEAM in the ACTUATIONS.

In the given example, I would like to get as result:

```
Operator #Actuations (count) Time(sum)   'Origin (only for clarifying, list not needed)
Peter    1                   5           'from actuation #4
Paul     1                   30          'from actuation #6
John     2                   45          'form actuations #3 and #5
```

Hope now it's more clear

EDIT 2:

You have a working example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91373/6/0

That's the desired result, but obviously I would not be able to use unions as I would not know the Operators.

Comment: What you will do when it will be necessary to add one more operator to the team?

Comment: I have not designed that DataBase, If so, I would have done another Table 1 to Many. But thats not the question now.

Thanks

Comment: Give info and sample data for Actuation and Teamworks table. Then in plain english explain what do you want to achieve. You can also create sample datasets and queries in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3 . I think then somebody can help you how to proceed.

Comment: I didn't Know about sqlfiddle, I'm going to try to make an example

Comment: you can see a working example with the desired result here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91373/6/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

After OP having altered the question, here is a working query for your example:

```
select top 1000
o.name
, count(1)
, sum(a.time)
from OPERATORS o
left join (
   select 
     unpvt.Operator
   , unpvt.ColName
   , unpvt.name
   from 
      (select name, operator1, operator2, operator3, operator4, operator5, operator6, operator7 
      from TEAMWORKS) ot
   UNPIVOT (
      Operator FOR ColName IN (operator1, operator2, operator3, operator4, operator5, operator6, operator7)
   ) as unpvt
) tw on o.name = tw.Operator
left join ACTUATION a on a.team = tw.name
where a.operator != o.name
group by o.name
```

This returns your decired result :)

**Old Post:**
I don't know the structure of the database, but I've had a go at guessing.

Firstly, i create to temporary tables in T-SQL - this is done for testing.
I've previously been down-voted for using temporary tables without descriptions in answers on SO for being to complicated, so please ask if you don't understand

```
declare @ACTUATION table(
  time datetime default getdate()
, Operator varchar(8)
, Workteam varchar(8)
)

insert into @ACTUATION (Operator, Workteam)
          select 'Gunnar', 'Peter'
union all select 'Peter', 'Gunnar'
```

We also need the table Teamworks:

```
declare @TEAMWORKS table(
  time datetime default getdate()
, sometext varchar(32)
, operator1 varchar(8)
, operator2 varchar(8)
, operator3 varchar(8)
, operator4 varchar(8)
, operator5 varchar(8)
, operator6 varchar(8)
, operator7 varchar(8)
)

insert into @TEAMWORKS(sometext, operator1, operator2, operator3, operator4, operator5, operator6, operator7)
          select 'Blah Blah', 'Gunnar', 'Jack', 'Sam', 'Joe', 'Lee', 'Jane', 'Jim'
union all select 'More Blah', 'Bob', 'Sal', 'Phil', 'Clark', 'Jones', 'Sue', 'Peter'
union all select 'Even more Blaah', 'Im', 'Running', 'out of', 'dummy', 'names', 'Peter', 'Gunnar'
```

What I've done here is to create two "virtual" tables, which only consist as variables. Eg. they are recreated each time the query is run. However, I think that they are a great tool when trying to visualize.

Next step is to UNPIVOT the operators to a more normalized structure.
This is done using the following query:

```
select 
  unpvt.time
, unpvt.sometext
, unpvt.Operator
, unpvt.ColName
from 
   (select time, sometext, operator1, operator2, operator3, operator4, operator5, operator6, operator7 
   from @TEAMWORKS) ot
UNPIVOT (
   Operator FOR ColName IN (operator1, operator2, operator3, operator4, operator5, operator6, operator7)
) as unpvt;
```

This query should make a great starting point for further joins.

For instance, I assume that this is (partly) the result you want:

```
select 
  a.Operator
, count(1)
, max(t.time)
from @ACTUATION a
left join (
   select 
   unpvt.Operator
   , unpvt.time
   from (
      select time, sometext, operator1, operator2, operator3, operator4, operator5, operator6, operator7 
      from @TEAMWORKS
   ) ot
   UNPIVOT (
      Operator FOR ColName IN (operator1, operator2, operator3, operator4, operator5, operator6, operator7)
   ) as unpvt
) t on a.Workteam = t.Operator
where a.Operator != t.Operator
group by a.Operator
```

Comment: I think that this would be the equivalent query you are talking about, but it doesn't work as espected:

select 
  a.Operator
, count(1)

from ACTUATION a
left join (
   select 
   unpvt.Operator
   
   from (
      select name, operator1, operator2, operator3, operator4, operator5, operator6, operator7 
      from TEAMWORKS
   ) ot
   UNPIVOT (
      Operator FOR ColName IN (operator1, operator2, operator3, operator4, operator5, operator6, operator7)
   ) as unpvt
) t on a.team = t.Operator
where a.Operator != t.Operator
group by a.Operator

Comment: I've updated the answer, after seeing your edits in OP. The query now returns your sample results